# Unable to start system in ubuntu

Tags: boot

I am trying to start my system. While trying to boot, I am getting

```
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
```

I attach an image of the problem I am facing.

[image]

Any solution?

Comment: related : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1658413

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that /dev/sda1 (the first partition of the first hard drive) has errors. In the screen shot you can see some details on the error and some advice on running FSCK manually.

I usually see this happen due to improper shutdown or power failure, but there are many reasons a file system can be corrupt.

Boot from your installation CD, and when you are presented with the option to install or try, select try. The button is usually titled "Try Ubuntu".

Once booted to a working desktop, open a terminal and type

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

This will run FSCK (File System ChecK) on /dev/sda1 and attempt to automatically repair errors as it goes.

If you don't want the automatic repair to happen, but prefer to acknowledge and repair each error manually, you can miss out the -y switch.

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda
```

I always include the -y, but it is up to you.